# Unbounded knapsack solution with items of equal value

Tags: performance, algorithm, ruby, knapsack-problem

My solution correctly solves the problem, but I would like to optimize its performance. For a capacity of 7 and bars = [ 4, 1, 1, 2, 1], the output is 7.

```
def knapsack(capacity, bars)
    if capacity == 0 || bars.nil? || bars[0].nil?
        return 0
    end

    solutions = []
    sum = 0
    (1..capacity).each do |i|
        break if sum > capacity
        bars.combination(i).lazy.each do |comb|
            sum = comb.reduce(&:+)
            solutions << sum
        end
    end

    solutions.select{|i| i <= capacity}.max
end
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! I hope you get some good answers.

Comment: Just as a hint, you may want to look into solving the knapsack problem with dynamic programming.  It's not hard and is much more performant, especially for large data sets.  I can post an example solution later if you are interested.  Your code as posted looks like well written ruby but your algorithm is a sub-optimal brute-force approach.